# Alarm application, i have an menu option for saving alarm, but when i try to click save menu option, my application crashes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-menu

I am trying to make alarm clock application, where i have given a save option in menu in to save new alarm, how ever every time i try to save my application crashes.
I putting my log can anyone help me understanding problem in my app ??
few piece of my code are

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (item.getItemId()) {
/*checksonu case android.R.id.home: {
    finish();
    break;
} */
case R.id.action_save_alarm_details: {
    updateModelFromLayout();

    AlarmManagerHelper.cancelAlarms(this);

    if (alarmDetails.id < 0) {
        dbHelper.createAlarm(alarmDetails);
    } else {
        dbHelper.updateAlarm(alarmDetails);
    }

    AlarmManagerHelper.setAlarms(this);

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

---

```
public static void setAlarms(Context context) {
cancelAlarms(context);

AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(context);

List<AlarmModel> alarms = dbHelper.getAlarms();

for (AlarmModel alarm : alarms) {
if (alarm.isEnabled) {

    PendingIntent pIntent = createPendingIntent(context, alarm);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm.timeHour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm.timeMinute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    //Find next time to set
    final int nowDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    final int nowHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int nowMinute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    boolean alarmSet = false;

    //First check if it's later in the week
    for (int dayOfWeek = Calendar.SUNDAY; dayOfWeek <= Calendar.SATURDAY; ++dayOfWeek) {
        if (alarm.getRepeatingDay(dayOfWeek - 1) && dayOfWeek >= nowDay &&
                !(dayOfWeek == nowDay && alarm.timeHour < nowHour) &&
                !(dayOfWeek == nowDay && alarm.timeHour == nowHour && alarm.timeMinute <= nowMinute)) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

            setAlarm(context, calendar, pIntent);
            alarmSet = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    //Else check if it's earlier in the week
    if (!alarmSet) {
        for (int dayOfWeek = Calendar.SUNDAY; dayOfWeek <= Calendar.SATURDAY; ++dayOfWeek) {
            if (alarm.getRepeatingDay(dayOfWeek - 1) && dayOfWeek <= nowDay && alarm.repeatWeekly) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
                calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);

                setAlarm(context, calendar, pIntent);
                alarmSet = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is the third time you posted this question (though you deleted your other ones) and you still have not posted your stack trace which people have asked for in every one of your questions

Comment: You may have better luck using [an Android developer support site](http://www.andglobe.com) in a language that is more comfortable for you.

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't check logcat entries. If application crashes, then surely a stack trace is printed in the logcat.

you need to save logcat entries in a file and then paste it here from file.